# Convert Java HashMap<String, Class<?>> into c#

Tags: java, c#, class, syntax, migration

I have a piece of Java code I need to translate in C#, and I have issue converting the following function.

The problem is how to convert the Class<?> Type and how to use it in the C# code. The rest is a quite straightforward conversion from Java `HashMap` to C# `Dictionary`

```
public final static String NULL_RULE= "NoRule";

public HashMap<String, Class<?>> getRulers() {
    HashMap<String, Class<?>> ruler= new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    ruler.put(NULL_RULE, NullRule.class);

    // Other ruler.put() instructions here, with different rules implementations
    // all implementing the same RuleExecutor interface
    
    return ruler;
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Type>` and `NullRule.class` is  `typeof(NullRule)`

Answer (score 1):

I also looking for the best replacement of <?>. For Java type Class the solution from Selvin is the result.
Some (other) Java to C# hacks a stored under https://github.com/bastie/NetVampire/blob/main/docs/DeveloperInformations.md